# Heroku CLI uses different email address from what I log in with

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

1) I authenticate with my Heroku credentials:

```
➡  temp heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: max@gbl.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Logged in as max@gbl.com

➡  temp heroku auth
max@gbl.com
```

2) I try to git-clone a repository, just to see that Heroku tries to use a *different* address:

```
➡  temp git clone git@heroku.com:some-edited-repository.git
Cloning into 'some-edited-repository'...

 !  Your account my-edited-address@gmail.com does not have access to some-edited-repository.
 !
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: d8:0f:75:21:88:24:47:bd:86:7f:33:26:7a:c9:22:88

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Where does Heroku pull that wrong email address from?

Answer (score 0):

your ssh key probably, switch your project to use http git with `heroku git:remote -a appname`